# Plot high frequency returns

Tags: r, plot, xts

I am trying to plot an xts object which contains 5-minute returns that span from 2015-01-01 until 2015-12-31, with the following code:

```
library(xts)
as.xts(dummy_fivemin)
plot(dummy_fivemin[,4], auto.grid = FALSE, major.ticks = "auto", 
                            minor.ticks = FALSE, col = "red") #plot
legend(x="topleft", legend = "EUR/AUD", lty = 1, col= "red")
```

which produces the following plot
[image]

I would like to make my plot look more professional, like the following graph taken from [Forecasting exchange rate volatility using high-frequency data: Is the euro different?](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207011000069)  [image]

Comment: This should get you started: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html